# When to use Dart/Flutter Isolate?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, dart-isolates

I read about dart [concurrency](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency#performance-and-isolate-groups). CMIIW, we should use `isolate` to not block UI render in flutter. But, I found that `isolate.spawn` is significantly slower.

So, why we should isolate? isn't it better to just use the main than to wait a whole lot longer?

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() async {
  final jsonStr = '{'
      '"name": "alif",'
      '"age": 26,'
      '"gender": "male",'
      '"office": "work from home"'
      '}';

  Future asyncRun<Q>(Function(Q) function, Q message) async {
    function(message);
  }

  final stopwatchA = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  }
  print('100 sync run     : ${stopwatchA.elapsed}');

  final stopwatchB = Stopwatch()..start();
  await Future.wait(
    [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) asyncRun(jsonDecode, jsonStr)],
  );
  print('100 async run    : ${stopwatchA.elapsed}');

  final stopwatchC = Stopwatch()..start();
  await Future.wait(
    [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) Isolate.spawn(jsonDecode, jsonStr)],
  );
  print('100 isolate.spawn: ${stopwatchC.elapsed}');
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

after i read [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417324/when-to-use-dart-flutter-isolate#comment124476414_70417324) from jamesdlin about spawn time.

I update the code. I expand the json and use only a single isolate. I found the isolate run much faster. But I don't understand, why is that happened? I expect slightly worse or similar time at best.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() async {
  final N = 1000;
  String content = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    content += '"content$i": $i';
    if (i != N - 1) content += ',';
  }
  final jsonStr = '{$content}';

  Future asyncRun<Q>(Function(Q) function, Q message) async {
    function(message);
  }

  final stopwatchA = Stopwatch()..start();
  jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  print('$N content sync run     : ${stopwatchA.elapsed}');

  final stopwatchB = Stopwatch()..start();
  await asyncRun(jsonDecode, jsonStr);
  print('$N content async run    : ${stopwatchA.elapsed}');

  final stopwatchC = Stopwatch()..start();
  await Isolate.spawn(jsonDecode, jsonStr);
  print('$N content isolate run  : ${stopwatchC.elapsed}');
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It depends.  If you're doing work that will take a long time, the time to spawn the isolate relative to the time spent doing real work will be less significant.  In those cases, you also don't want to the UI to be blocked and to stop responding.

Comment: I've learnt more about this thing since last time. It's indeed as you said. Previously, I do not understand clearly about the "time to spawn". My first result took so long because I spawn a lot isolate. While the second result is confusing because the time measured is not the correct one, it only measure one isolate spawn time not the whole json decoding. I write my whole experiment here https://gist.github.com/alifgiant/42bb081a8be4873c96c09c8dd9bad9eb

Answer (score 2):

Using isolates, your Dart code can perform multiple independent tasks at once, using additional processor cores if they're available. Isolates are like threads or processes, but each isolate has its own memory and a single thread running an event loop.

**The main isolate**

You often don’t need to think about isolates at all. A typical Dart app executes all its code in the app’s main isolate,
Even single-isolate programs can execute smoothly by using async-await to wait for asynchronous operations to complete before continuing to the next line of code. A well-behaved app starts quickly, getting to the event loop as soon as possible. The app then responds to each queued event promptly, using asynchronous operations as necessary.

**The isolate life cycle**
As the following figure shows, every isolate starts by running some Dart code, such as the main() function. This Dart code might register some event listeners—to respond to user input or file I/O, for example. When the isolate’s initial function returns, the isolate stays around if it needs to handle events. After handling the events, the isolate exits.

**Event handling**
In a client app, the main isolate’s event queue might contain repaint requests and notifications of tap and other UI events. For example, the following figure shows a repaint event, followed by a tap event, followed by two repaint events. The event loop takes events from the queue in first in, first out order.

[Official Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency#:%7E:text=Using%20isolates%2C%20your%20Dart%20code,thread%20running%20an%20event%20loop.)

Answer (score 0):

When do somthing which use a lot of cpu time,
if it run on main isolate, the UI will blocked.
isolate.spawn is the best way.